# Solutions of $\sqrt{x+4+2\sqrt{x+3}}-(x^2+4x+3)^{1/3}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, radicals

$\sqrt{x+4+2\sqrt{x+3}}-(x^2+4x+3)^{1/3}=1$

I get that $-3$ as a solution, but apparently 1 is as well a solution, and I don't see a mechanism through which I could find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: who made this problem up? what is the purpose?

Comment: It's an exercise in my textbook which I am trying to solve. It actually asks for the sum of the absolute values of its solutions, and claims it should be 1. I see no way it could be 1, so I asked here.

Comment: $x+4+2\sqrt{x+3}=\left(\sqrt{x+3}\right)^2+2\sqrt{x+3}+1 = \left(\sqrt{x+3}+1\right)^2$ . Also, $x^2+4x+3=(x+1)(x+3)$. Does this help?

Comment: I indeed got that. I wonder how do you get mathematically to realizing $1$ is a solution. Graphically, I got $-3$,

Comment: Where in what book?

Comment: It's a textbook for a Serbian math-specializing high school. It was one of the exercises on their tests in their sophomore year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we have $$\sqrt{x+4+2\sqrt{x+3}}-(x^2+4x+3)^{1/3}=1 $$ let us make a change of variable $u = x + 3 \ge 0, x = u - 3.$ with that we have 
$$\sqrt{u+1+2\sqrt u}-(u(u-2))^{1/3}=1 \to 1+\sqrt u=(u(u-2))^{1/3}+1$$ this gives us $$\sqrt u = (u(u-2))^{1/3}\tag 1 $$

now, exponentiating  $(1)$ implies $$ 0=u^3 - u^2(u-2)^2 \to 0=u^2(u^2 -5u + 4)=u^2(u-4)(u-1) $$

subbing  $u = 1,$ in $(1),$ we have $1 = -1$ therefore is an extraneous solution and needs to be rejected.

the roots are $u = 0, u = 4$ are solutions of $1.$ this translates to $$x = -3, x = 1. $$

Comment: Yep, that sounds right. Is this a problem that can be solved without changing variables?

Comment: @JohnDoe, sure. the change of variable makes it easier to see. i may not  have seen $\sqrt{u+1+2\sqrt u} = \sqrt u + 1$ without it.

Comment: Actually, $0=u^2(u^2-5u+4)=u^2(u-4)(u-1)$. But $u=1$ doesn't give a solution- the solution set is still $\{-3,1\}$.

Comment: @user26486, i am sorry, i don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @abel the last implication $\to$ is false.

Comment: @user26486, i don't think so.

Comment: He means that $u=1$ is a solution to that equation he quoted, but it's not a solution of the original equation.
@user26486 This usually happens when you apply irreversible operations to an equation, the last polynomial gives a list of 4 possible solutions of the original equation, which you should check to see which of those remain.

Comment: $u^3-u^2(u-2)^2=u^2(u-(u-2)^2)=u^2(u-u^2+4u-4)=u^2(-u^2+5u-4) \neq u^2(-u^2+3u-4)$

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD no, his arithmetic has mistakes.

Comment: @user26486, i see that. i missed the sign. thank you.